# Compiling your website against a specific version of the .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I don't have access to an IIS server but I am told that the site is configured to run with version 1.1 of the .NET Framework. When I use Telerik JustDecompile I see the following.

[image]

The "NET 1" seems to suggest that the 2 dlls are compiled against version 1.1 of the FW. Does the "ANY" next to the website dll "GLSS" indicate that the site can run against any version ofthe .NET FW that is installed on the web server?

In preparation for an upgrade to 2.0, I have asked the web admins to change the site configuration to version 2.0 of the FW and I was surprised that the site, which I considered to be running 1.1 code, still worked. Should I be surprised?

Is this just a simple example of backward compatability and that the site could be configured to use any version of the framework provided that it was equal to or higher than the version that the code was compiled to use?

when I look at the property pages for the projects in the solution, I was surprised that, for the website project only, I was unable to locate where one sets the version of the FW which you want to compile against. I was able to locate it for the referenced projects.

Can you help me better understand the relationship between the version of teh FW that a site is configured and the versions that the assemblies are compiled against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be surprised, .NET was always backward compatible in a sense that assemblies compiled against a version of the runtime are supposed to run against a newer version of the runtime.

There are of course subtle issues where things are not backward compatible, starting from subtle semantic differences and ending with changes at the object contract level (where the expected method/class just does not exists anymore) but in general these problems depend on the complexity of your application. It is safe to assume that simple applications should just work with no issues.

The number of the runtime the assembly has been complied against is a part of the assembly's metadata, it can be read with reflection. Thus, at runtime, you have at least two possible versions of the runtime - the one the assembly has been compiled against and the current version of the runtime which executes your code.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm still wondering why I don't see the option to select the version of the FW that the main website dll is compiled against and why the Telerik app, which uses reflection, is showing " any " as the version...

Comment: You CAN change the version of the runtime that compiles your website. This is known as "multi targeting" and is available starting from VS2008 or 2010 as far as I remember. There are selected number of frameworks you can choose, however, so for example, this is not possible to target .NET 1.0 or 1.1 with multi targeting (only selected number of newer versions is available).